# How to convert ms word file with image and equation into html with the help memoryStream in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using as below coding and it is working fine. These programming convert word file into html file with image.

There is problem in equation.I am unable to convert ms word file equation HTML.

Can anybody help?

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName));

string imageDirectoryName = FileUpload1.FileName + "_files";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(imageDirectoryName));

if (dirInfo.Exists)
{
        // Delete the directory and files.
        foreach (var f in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            f.Delete();
        dirInfo.Delete();
}

int imageCounter = 0;

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceDocumentFileName);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
        memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
        {
            HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
            {
                //PageTitle = "Test Title",
                //ConvertFormatting = false,
            };
            XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings,
                imageInfo =>
                {
                    DirectoryInfo localDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(imageDirectoryName));
                    if (!localDirInfo.Exists)
                        localDirInfo.Create();
                    ++imageCounter;
                    string extension = imageInfo.ContentType.Split('/')[1].ToLower();
                    ImageFormat imageFormat = null;
                    if (extension == "png")
                    {
                        // Convert the .png file to a .jpeg file.
                        extension = "jpeg";
                        imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    }
                    else if (extension == "bmp")
                        imageFormat = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                    else if (extension == "jpeg")
                        imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    else if (extension == "tiff")
                        imageFormat = ImageFormat.Tiff;
                    else if (extension == "wmf")
                        imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    else if (extension == "png")
                        imageFormat = ImageFormat.Png;


                    // If the image format is not one that you expect, ignore it,
                    // and do not return markup for the link.
                    if (imageFormat == null)
                        return null;

                    string imageFileName = imageDirectoryName + "/image" +
                        imageCounter.ToString() + "." + extension;
                    try
                    {
                        imageInfo.Bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath(imageFileName), imageFormat);
                    }
                    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    XElement img = new XElement(Xhtml.img,
                        new XAttribute(NoNamespace.src, imageFileName),
                        imageInfo.ImgStyleAttribute,
                        imageInfo.AltText != null ?
                            new XAttribute(NoNamespace.alt, imageInfo.AltText) : null);
                    return img;
                });
            File.WriteAllText(fileInfo.Directory.FullName + "/" + fileInfo.Name.Substring(0,
                fileInfo.Name.Length - fileInfo.Extension.Length) + ".html",
                html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: actually given coding convert word file to html with image but if i am using Mathematical equation, it is not showing in html page

Comment: How is the mathematical equation expressed in the word document?

Comment: a (x+a)^n=∑_(k=0)^n▒〖(n¦k) x^k a^(n-k) 〗

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** - You should go here to get understand how to get Math object in word file [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65666/how-to-programmatically-extract-mathematical-formulas-from-word-with-mathematica)

**Step 2** - Loop through Paragraphs of word file and select OfficeMath object in it, transform it to **MathML** (see step 1), and can transform to LaTex if you want (I think use LaTex will be friendly when use in HTML)

Note: Transform to **LaTex** will be similar when Transform from **MMOL2MML** in step 1 [see here to get file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltml/)

**Step 3** - Insert befor/after object in step 2 a text object with content is MathML/LaTex (in step 2). Use this step because when use `HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml` will miss math object in Word content so when you insert before/after object math a text will be available in HTML

This is my code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docFilePath, true))
        {
            foreach (var paragraph in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>())
            {
                foreach (var ele in paragraph.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.OfficeMath>())
                {
                    string wordDocXml = ele.OuterXml;

                    XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslTransform.Load(officeMathMLSchemaFilePath);
                    var result = "";
                    using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(wordDocXml))
                    {
                        // Load the xml of your main document part.
                        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(tr))
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                XmlWriterSettings settings = xslTransform.OutputSettings.Clone();

                                // Configure xml writer to omit xml declaration.
                                settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
                                settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

                                XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

                                // Transform our OfficeMathML to MathML.
                                xslTransform.Transform(reader, xw);
                                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                                {
                                    result = MathML2Latex(sr.ReadToEnd());
                                    officeMLFormulas.Add(result);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Run run = new Run();
                    run.Append(new Text(result));
                    ele.InsertBeforeSelf(run);
                }
            }
        }
```